Filter out team members who are invited to a party
I have a list of my team members ~300 of us. There is also another list of invitees to a party ~4,000 persons. How do I find out which team members are being invited to the party?
Here's a scaled down example. Note that the invitee names are in varying formats:
my_team_list = ['Andy', 'Bernice', 'Charlotte', 'David', 'Evan']
invitee_list = ['Mandy (Team A)', 'Navin - Team A', 'Olive Team B', 'Peter Team C', 'Queenie (D)', 'Royston -D team', 'Steven (E team)', 'Tammy (E team)', 'Bernice (Z team)', 'Victor (A Team)', 'Wendy (Team B)', 'David (Team Z)']

for name in my_team_list:
    for invitee in invitee_list:
        if name in invitee:
            print(invitee)

#output
Bernice (Z team)
David (Team Z)

The above code is a brute force example of getting the solution, but the time complexity is O(n x m). I am wondering is there a more efficient way to get this done?

Try to use a dictionary.

You can make it at least a bit more efficient if you join the team members with | to a regex expression (additional escaping may be necessary). You can then in a loop search for this expression in the invitee_list.

Looks like you only have first name in both the lists. So you could clean up the invitee_list by splitting it by space and then do a set intersection.
my_team_list = ['Andy', 'Bernice', 'Charlotte', 'David', 'Evan']
invitee_list = ['Mandy (Team A)', 'Navin - Team A', 'Olive Team B', 'Peter Team C', 'Queenie (D)', 'Royston -D team', 'Steven (E team)', 'Tammy (E team)', 'Bernice (Z team)', 'Victor (A Team)', 'Wendy (Team B)', 'David (Team Z)']

for i in range(len(invitee_list)):
    invitee_list[i] = invitee_list[i].split(" ")[0]

print(set(my_team_list)&set(invitee_list))


If your format is more complex than you've posted (e.g. there are names with spaces in them, or other funny characters), you might consider using a regular expression:
import re
my_team_list = ['Andy', 'Bernice', 'Charlotte', 'David', 'Evan']
invitee_list = ['Mandy (Team A)', 'Navin - Team A', 'Olive Team B', 'Peter Team C', 'Queenie (D)', 'Royston -D team', 'Steven (E team)', 'Tammy (E team)', 'Bernice (Z team)', 'Victor (A Team)', 'Wendy (Team B)', 'David (Team Z)']
my_team_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(name) for name in my_team_list))
for name in invitee_list:
    if my_team_re.search(name):
        print(name)

This is guaranteed to behave the same as your current solution, but should run substantially faster, as it will run in O(n+m) time.

I'd convert invitee_list to a dict to be accessed directly by key.
my_team_list = ['Andy', 'Bernice', 'Charlotte', 'David', 'Evan']
invitee_list = ['Mandy (Team A)', 'Navin - Team A', 'Olive Team B', 'Peter Team C', 'Queenie (D)', 'Royston -D team', 'Steven (E team)', 'Tammy (E team)', 'Bernice (Z team)', 'Victor (A Team)', 'Wendy (Team B)', 'David (Team Z)']

invitee_list_dict = {name.split(' ')[0] : name for name in invitee_list}

#=> {'Mandy': 'Mandy (Team A)', 'Navin': 'Navin - Team A', ...}

I used list comprehension to present a list of result as res, but you can do whatever you want.
res = [invitee_list_dict[k] for k in my_team_list if k in invitee_list_dict.keys()]

#=> ['Bernice (Z team)', 'David (Team Z)']

